# Have "Interesting Tags" that are combinations of tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags

There are many tags that can have multiple uses.  This is fine and good.  However, it would help in finding questions that I can actually answer if there was a way to join tags for my *Interesting Tags* and *Ignored Tags*.

Here is an example to make it clearer:

---

Tags:  **Generics** and **.Net**

or

Tags: **Generics** and **Java**

---

The first one I can help with.  The second one I know very little about.  I know a bit about Java in general, so I don't want to add that to my ignore list, but I am not much help with a deep Java Generics issue.

This would also help some with categorization.  There are tags like [wpf-binding].  That tag is used because databinding can be for WPF or other things.  This leads me to tag my WPF Databinding questions with both (wpf-binding and databinding)

Anyway, I am not dying to have this feature, it just hit me as a good idea so I thought I would throw it out there.

Answer (score 6):

You can already do this! Just define an Interesting tag that is a combination of the ones you want.

e.g. in the Interesting Tags box, type `[tags]+[bug]` (including the square brackets). Be careful not to let the auto-completion change it. Click the Add button, and you have an interesting tag like this:-

[image]

Click its button, and you get a search which finds answers which are tagged "tags" and "bug".

Comment: While this lets you in effect bookmark a search, it doesn't actually make the combination highlighted as interesting or ignored.

Answer (score 5):

You can have it right now if you search via tags, excluding those you don't want to mess with.

In your case, it would be:

> [**[generics] [.net] -[java]**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net+generics+-java)

Which pulls up all the questions tagged both **[generics]** and **[.net]**, excluding those that happen to be tagged **[java]**.

Comment: more so, I think he is talking about synonyms

Answer (score 4):

The search option is great, but I would like an option to store this search criteria as a tag (so that I could click this tag and have all answers which could be answered by me (mind you, I would use other tags than Vaccano)).

Comment: +1 Me too.  I currently keep a browser bookmark that links to ".../oracle or oracle9i or oracle10g or oracle11g or plsql", but that only works when I'm on this particular PC.  It would be great to be able to do it from within SO - i.e. show me questions that match any of my "interesting" tags.