# Official repository of tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, repository

> The purpose of this page has been **obsoleted** by the implementation of the [tag synonym feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57479/13992).
>
> **[See the list of currently implemented tag synonyms.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all)**

---

#### Purpose

I think it would be a good idea to keep all the potential tag synonyms in one spot, since a lot of that information is currently fragmented across many retag request questions and answers (particularly my own). There are also additional synonyms that can be put here, as I rarely post a request when I retag a set of questions -- the synonym information gets lost when I finish cleaning up.

Once a [tag synonym system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms) is implemented, using this repository will make it easy to get all the major synonyms into the system.

This question will be SO-centric (for obvious reasons), but should be able to apply to the whole Trilogy: currently, some tags are kept differently on SU vs. SO, for example, but a synonyms system should bring all the tags into line between the sites. I'm most familiar with SO, but feel free to add synonyms from the other sites.

This repository will also be useful for retaggers to check on certain tags to keep them clean. However, some of these synonyms *are not currently followed in the system*. So if you see a master/synonym pair with 800/700 questions or 80/10 in the *wrong direction*, it's probably best to do nothing about it yet, or clean up based on the highly dominant tag.

#### Format

Based on my [personal proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms/49872#49872) for the synonym system, this repository will contain a set of master tags, and all synonyms of that master tag. I believe that's generic enough to fit the model of any potential synonym system.

Please try to follow the format I've started in the seed answers:

- Group synonyms by major topic, and use one answer per topic (I'd like to minimize the number of answers in this question so searching using your web browser is easy)
- Put all master tags in **bold** so they stand out
- Keep the lists of tags in alphabetical order as much as possible so it's easy to find existing tags
- Please search the question for a tag that's going to be added -- it may already be here, or lumped in with the [miscellaneous tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms/50089#50089)

Any extended discussion about a potential synonym should be done in its own question, and update the appropriate answer in this question when consensus is reached. I'd like to keep the answers in here clean so there's no guesswork as to what goes in and what is left out -- fair warning that I will be aggressively flagging comments to help remove suggestions/notifications of updates as they are completed. Thanks!

#### Repository Index

- [Adobe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms/50687#50687)
- [C#, VB.NET, .NET, ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms/50094#50094)
- [Database](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms/50093#50093)
- [IDEs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms/50100#50100)
- [International English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms/53001#53001)
- [Java, Java EE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms/50098#50098)
- [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms/52664#52664)
- [Microsoft Office](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms/50121#50121)
- [Operating Systems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms/50118#50118)
- [Other Programming Languages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms/50092#50092)
- [Version Control, and Related Software](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms/50091#50091)
- [Web Browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms/50090#50090)
- [Miscellaneous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms/50089#50089)

Comment: Does it make sense to keep a set of tags related to versions, so instead of [asp.net-mvc-2-rtm] we should have [asp.net-mvc-2] + [rtm], and instead of [asp.net-mvc-2-beta] we should have [asp.net-mvc-2] + [beta] ?

Comment: Also, instead of [ioc-container] is it ok to use [inversion-of-control] + [container] ?

Comment: @alex: Tags should be unambiguous. If we introduced a `[beta]` tag, it doesn't really mean much as a category. `[ioc-container]` should become `[inversion-of-control-container]`, but that's too long for a tag name. I'm not certain what to do with that specific example right now. Also, this may be of interest as well: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41206/should-questions-be-tagged-with-both-a-tag-and-a-sub-tag

Comment: It would be great if the engine behind these sites could use this (or some other) kind of community-driven aliasing to auto-correct synonymous tags. Maybe something behind a reputation firewall, though, to keep people of low repute (literally and figuratively) from abusing the system.

Comment: @fbrereto: Yes, please see the first two links in my post, above.

Comment: I'm not convinced all synonyms should be global across all the sites.  (And depending on how things go with StackExchange, that could become *definitely not*.)  'Sides, then we can [linkify the tags](http://codepad.org/MwIL5itZ "with my preferred formatting shown :)").

Comment: @The Cat: Can you cite a counter-example where a tag group (with master/synonym tags) would not be valid across the Trilogy? (I'm not saying some of the synonyms here *would* apply to all sites, just that if those topics exist on all sites -- such as operating system related tags -- the groupings here should be used.) Also, this repository is not meant for StackExchange sites... the topics of those are, for all intents and purposes, completely unlimited, so they'll have to deal with tag synonyms on their own.

Comment: Podcast 87 (oldish by now, but I listened to it recently) talked quite a bit (but no specific plans) about creating "wider"/larger communities and behavior, as contrasted with how all other SE sites are segregated now.  That's the possibility I was referring to.  I remember seeing a problem pointed out with a [retag-request] across sites with tags having different meanings, but I can't find it now.  I agree many of them could be shared across SO/SU/SF.  @jon

Comment: Okay, fair enough... but honestly I don't see how that would bring about an objection about sharing tags across sites. Could you clarify that for me?

Comment: A `[bug]` tag would have a completely different meaning on *stackoverflow* and *my-housekeeping-advice* (sorry, couldn't think of anything better at this hour ;).

Comment: @3chars: When I say "across sites," I'm talking about the Trilogy sites -- StackExchange is a completely separate beast.

Comment: @Jon: Counter example: [alt] could mean several different things, such as img's alt attribute, the alt key on keyboards, an alternate in a tournament (if a SE site is ever set up around sporting), alternating elements, or other kinds of alteratives.  Adding [alt] to any global synonym list would be problematic.

Comment: @The Cat: `[alt]` can be disambiguated to `[alt-attribute]` and `[alt-key]`, following your examples. I'm still not sure you're understanding, though -- this repository is for SOFU *only*, *not* for any SE sites.

Comment: @Jon: It can be manually disambiguated, but it can't be automatically synonymed.  Only the sporting even use of "alternate" applies to other SE sites from the list I gave.  I understand what you mean for *this* list, but presumably other sites will need a synonym list if the Trilogy does, so I'm also trying to think in a bigger picture at the same time.

Comment: @The Cat: Right, I never said `[alt]` should be handled automatically. What *should* happen in those situations is to manually disambiguate the tags, then blacklist the ambiguous tag. And yes, it's possible other sites will need a synonym system, but as the SE sites start up, it will be easier for them if they already have a system in place to start than on SO where there's a huge amount of existing data. Regardless, the SE sites vary in topic so much, there would need to be a list for each site, without much crossover.

Comment: @Jon: Would you mind if I went through all of these answers and linkified them?  I can use out-of-band syntax ([abc][#]) if that would be easier to edit than [inline URLs](http://codepad.org/MwIL5itZ).

Comment: @The Cat: Hmmm... My first reaction was to decline your offer, but just so we can see how difficult to edit these might become, go ahead and do one of them, and we can roll back if it's too cumbersome. (I'm also hesitant since some of the tags apply to multiple sites, not just SO). I know -- do the Meta one, down at the bottom and we can see how it turns out (yes, please, use the non-inline URLs... I found the inline ones almost impossible to edit around in the other question).

Comment: @Jon: I usually find inline just all-around better.. though it's never as dense as these will be.  However, figured you'd be editing here, not me.  Posted as a separate answer, so you can compare how they'll be used, too.  Ping me whenever you want it deleted.

Comment: Makes a [big difference](http://i47.tinypic.com/166bzw3.jpg) for me, BTW, but maybe that's just me.  (I prefer good variable-width fonts for source code, too...)

Comment: Tag synonyms is implemented, time to start feeding these puppies into the system

Comment: @waffles: EXCELLENT. Can I help in any way?

Comment: @Jon I guess posting synonym requests on meta? Its a moderator only function for now, but I am running all of these past Marc and Bill before adding

Comment: @waffles: Yeah, sorry, I read your comment reply before getting to your post about how it was implemented. Everything in here should be good to go. Carry on.

Comment: @Jon we are probably looking at doing another rev of this feature, hold tight for a few day.

Comment: I made some SEDE queries to catch singular/plural pairs http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/112/most-common-tags-with-singular-and-plural-version-es-plural and http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/111/most-common-tags-with-singular-and-plural-version-s-plural

Answer (score 7):

### Java, Java EE

---

**`[applet]`**: `[applets]`

**`[bean-validation]`**: `[jsr303]`

**`[ejb-3.0]`**: `[ejb3]`, `[ejb-3]`, `[ejb3.0]`
**`[ejb-3.1]`**: `[ejb31]`, `[ejb-31]`, `[ejb3.1]`

**`[glassfish-3]`**: `[glassfish3]`, `[glassfishv3]`, `[glassfish-v3]`

**`[hibernate-3]`**: `[hibernate3]`

**`[jakarta-commons-logging]`**: `[apache-commons-logging]`

**`[java-2d]`**: `[java2d]`
**`[java-3d]`**: `[java3d]`

**`[java-1.4]`**: `[java1.4]`, `[java14]`
**`[java-5]`**: `[java5]`, `[java5.0]`, `[java-5.0]`
**`[java-6]`**: `[java6]`, `[java6.0]`, `[java-6.0]`
**`[java-7]`**: `[java7]`, `[java7.0]`, `[java-7.0]`

**`[java-applets]`**: `[java-applet]` (these can't be synonyms of `[applets]` to avoid collisions with e.g. Gnome stuff).

**`[java-ee]`**: `[javaee]`, `[jee]`
**`[java-ee-5]`**: `[javaee5]`, `[javaee-5]`, `[java-ee5]`, `[jee5]`, `[jee-5]`
**`[java-ee-6]`**: `[javaee6]`, `[javaee-6]`, `[java-ee6]`, `[jee6]`, `[jee-6]`

**`[java-fx]`**: `[javafx]`

**`[java-io]`**: `[javaio]`, `[java.io]`

**`[jax-rs]`**: `[jaxrs]`

**`[jax-ws]`**: `[jaxws]`

**`[jpa-2.0]`**: `[jpa2]`, `[jpa-2]`, `[jpa2.0]`

**`[jsf-2.0]`**: `[jsf2]`, `[jsf-2]`, `[jsf2.0]`

**`[jsp-tags]`**: `[jsp-tag]`, `[jsp-tag-files]`, `[jsp-tagfiles]`
**`[jsp-fragments]`**: `[jspfragments]`, `[jsp-fragment]`, `[jspfragment]`, `[jsp-f]`, `[jspf]`

**`[maven-2]`**: `[maven2]`

**`[servlets]`**: `[servlet]`
**`[servlet-filters]`**: `[servletfilter]`, `[servlet-filter]`, `[servletfilters]`, `[servlet]`+`[filter]`, `[servlet]`+`[filters]`, `[servlets]`+`[filter]`, `[servlets]`+`[filters]`

**`[tomcat-5.0]`**: `[tomcat5]`, `[tomcat-5]`, `[tomcat5.0]`
**`[tomcat-5.5]`**: `[tomcat5.5]`
**`[tomcat-6.0]`**: `[tomcat6]`, `[tomcat-6]`, `[tomcat6.0]`

**`[weblogic-8.x]`**: `[weblogic8]`, `[weblogic-8]`, `[weblogic8.1]`, `[weblogic-8.1]`, `[weblogic8.x]`
**`[weblogic-9.x]`**: `[weblogic9]`, `[weblogic-9]` , `[weblogic9.x]`
**`[weblogic-10.x]`**: `[weblogic10]`,  `[weblogic-10]`, `[weblogic10.x]`
**`[weblogic-11g]`**: `[weblogic11]`, `[weblogic-11]`, `[weblogic11g]`

Comment: I added some. I actually tend to prefer `[servlet]` as the main tag. The choice for `[servlets]` was intentional since when one enters `servlet` in the list, they would see `servlets` in the option list, but the other way round you won't see it.

Comment: @BalusC: Feel free to put `[servlet]` as master. Also, I still have big doubts about `[java-ee-5]` and `[jee5]` (same for 6). The current suggestion just seems more consistent.

Comment: Exactly. I've the same doubts. But this system makes it possible to enter `jee5` and so on as tag and end up with the "correct" tag.

Comment: What is the heuristic behind preferring singular tags (e.g., `[applet]`) versus plural ones (e.g., `[jsp-tags]`)?

Comment: @fbrereto I don't know and I don't think there is any consensus. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6752/merge-singular-and-plural-tags, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47289/merging-singular-and-plural-forms-of-tags-closed.

Comment: Completely disagree with `applet`. Then you have Java stuff showing up with Gnome stuff

Comment: Then open a discussion question about it. @geo

Comment: @George You're right and I've split `[applets]` and `[java-applets]` (feel free to edit it yourself, that's what CW is for).

Comment: @Pascal Thivent: Should [tomcat5] [tomcat6] be different tags from [tomcat] ? A lot of time questions are not specific to version like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672859/why-is-jboss-better-than-tomcat - is the right response to edit the question and retag on SO?

Comment: @josek Good question :) Personally, I think that it makes sense to have different tags for questions where the version is relevant. But for questions like the one you linked to, *I* would indeed use the more generic [tomcat] and [jboss] tags, the question is definitely not version specific, a retag wouldn't look "wrong" IMO. And if you do retag it and the community disagree, it could always be reverted and discussed on meta. I put @BalusC in the loop as he is the one who added the tags and might have other things to say.

Answer (score 5):

### Miscellaneous

---

**`[beginner]`**: `[beginners]`, `[newbie]`, `[newb]`, `[n00b]`, `[noob]`, `[new-user]`, `[new-users]`, `[new-developer]`, `[new-developers]`, `[beginning]`

**`[digital-signal-processing]`**: `[signal-processing]`, `[dsp]`

**`[domain-specific-language]`**: `[dsl]`

**`[dont-repeat-yourself]`**: `[dry]` (needs reversing?)

**`[daylight-savings-time]`**: `[daylight-savings]`, `[dst]`, `[daylight]` (needs reversing?)

**`[history]`**: `[language-history]`

**`[images]`**: `[image]`, `[pictures]`, `[picture]` (needs reversing, and additional synonyms)

**`[large-files]`**: `[largefile]`, `[large]` + `[file]`, `[large]` + `[files]`, `[large-file]`, `[huge-files]`, `[huge-file]`, `[huge]` + `[file]`, `[huge]` + `[files]`, `[bigfile]`, `[bigfiles]`

**`[liskov-substitution]`**: `[lsp]`, `[liskov-substitution-prin]`, `[liskov-substitution-princ]` (needs reversing?)

**`[srp]`**: `[single-responsibility]`, `[single-responsibility-pri]`

**`[wi-fi]`**: `[wifi]`

**`[winapi]`**: `[win32api]`

Comment: What is the heuristic behind preferring singular tags (e.g., `[algorithm]`) versus plural ones (e.g., `[best-practices]`)?

Comment: @fbrereto: We prefer to use whichever is a more encompassing term. I suppose with `[algorithm]` we could go the other way, but if they're aliases of one another, then it's close enough to not matter.

Answer (score 4):

### IDEs

---

**`[eclipse-3.4]`**: `[eclipse-ganymede]`, `[eclipse]` + `[ganymede]`
**`[eclipse-3.5]`**: `[eclipse-galileo]`, `[eclipse]` + `[galileo]`
**`[eclipse-3.6]`**: `[eclipse-helios]`, `[eclipse]` + `[helios]`

**`[qt-creator]`**: `[qtcreator]`, `[qt]` + `[creator]`

**`[visual-c++]`**: `[vc++]`, `[visualc++]`, `[msvc++]`, `[msvc]`

**`[visual-studio]`**: `[visualstudio]`, `[visual]`+`[studio]`
**`[visual-studio-yyyy]`**: `[visualstudioyyyy]`, `[visual]`+`[studio]`+`[yyyy]`, `[vsyyyy]`
**`[visual-studio-yyyy-beta*]`**: `[vsyyyy-beta*]`

**`[visual-studio-express]`** + **`[visual-studio-yyyy]`**: `[visual-studio-yyyy-expres]`, `[visual-studio-express-yyy]` (not a typo - 25 char limit)
**`[visual-studio-express]`** + **`[visual-web-developer]`**: `[visual-web-developer-expr]`

**`[visual-studio-team-system]`**: `[team-system]`, `[teamsystem]`

**`[visual-web-developer]`**: `[visual-web]`

Answer (score 3):

### Version Control, and Related Software

---

**`[distributed-version-control]`**: `[dvcs]`, `[dscm]`

**`[hgignore]`**: `[.hgignore]`

**`[mercurial]`**: `[hg]`

**`[hgrc-mercurial.ini]`**: `[hgrc]`, `[mercurial.ini]`

**`[subversion]`**: `[svn]`

**`[tfs]`**: `[team-foundation-server]`, `[team-foundation]`
**`[tfsYYYY]`**: `[team-foundation-server-YYYY]`, `[team-foundation-YYYY]`
**`[tfsbuild]`**: `[team-foundation-build]`

**`[version-control]`**: `[source-control]`, `[source]` + `[control]`, `[revision-control]`, `[version]` + `[control]`, `[revision]` + `[control]`, `[scm]`, `[source-code-management]`

**`[visualhg]`**: `[visual-hg]` (Should this be reversed?)

**`[visual-sourcesafe]`**: `[vss]`
**`[visual-sourcesafe-200*]`**: `[vss200*]`

Comment: So far on SO [svn]=4732 and [subversion]=0. It's not so easy to retag all of them by hand, so should it be reversed to [svn]: [subversion] ?

Comment: There are many tags related to mercurial that starts with hg, while the tags that starts with [mercurial] are [mercurial-queue] and [mercurial.ini]. Does it make sense to promote hg instead of mercurial, so the whole mercurial related tags are easier to find?

Comment: @alex: Please re-read the question text above. This is not about determining the most popular tags -- it's about aliasing tags and then putting whichever alias we feel would best be displayed for a given topic (which is what a tag really denotes). There are a lot of tags in here that *do not follow* the most common pattern at the moment.

Comment: I'm just saying that [hg] could be IMHO the best way to promote mercurial, just like on SO a tag search on `svn` can be used to find every tag that is subversion-related, as the only tag containing `subversion` is [hgsubversion] which is mercurial-related.

Answer (score 3):

### C#, VB.NET, .NET, ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC

---

**`[.net]`**: `[dotnet]`

**`[asp.net]`**: `[asp-net]`

**`[asp.net-mvc]`**: `[asp-net-mvc]`
**`[asp.net-mvc-2]`**: `[asp-net-mvc2]`, `[asp-net-mvc-2]`, `[asp.net-mvc2]`, `[mvc2]`, `[mvc-2]`
**`[asp.net-mvc-2-rtm]`**: `[asp.net-mvc2-rtm]`

**`[c#]`**: `[csharp]`, `[c#.net]`
**`[c#-2.0]`**: `[c#2]`, `[c#2.0]`
**`[c#-3.0]`**: `[c#3]`, `[c#3.0]`
**`[c#-3.5]`**: `[c#3.5]`
**`[c#-4.0]`**: `[c#4]`, `[c#4.0]`

**`[entity-framework]`**: `[ef]`
**`[entity-framework-4]`**: `[ef4]`, `[entity-framework4]`

**`[winforms]`**: `[window-form]`, `[windows-form]`, `[window-forms]`, `[windows-forms]`
**`[windows-forms-designer]`**: `[windows-form-designer]`

**`[app-config]`**: `[app.config]`
**`[web-config]`**: `[web.config]`

Answer (score 3):

### Operating Systems

---

**`[google-chrome-os]`** : `[chrome-os]`

**`[i-os]`**: `[iphone-os]`, `[iphoneos]`
**`[i-os-*]`**: `[iphone-os-*]`, `[iphoneos*]`

**`[operating-system]`**: `[os]`, `[operating-systems]`, `[operating]` + `[system]`, `[operating]` + `[systems]`

**`[osx]`**: `[macosx]`

**`[snow-leopard]`**: `[macos10.6]`, `[osx-snow-leopard]`

**`[windows-ce]`**: `[wince]`

**`[windows-mobile]`**: `[windowsmobile]` + `[windows]` + `[mobile]`

**`[windows-server-2003]`**: `[win2k3]`, `[server-2003]`, `[windows]`+`[server]`+`[2003]`, `[server]`+`2003`
**`[windows-server-2008]`**: `[win2k8]`, `[windows]`+`[server]`+`[2008]`, `[server]`+`[2008]`

**`[windows-vista]`**: `[vista]`, `[windows]` + `[vista]`

**`[windows-xp]`**: `[windowsxp]`, `[windows]` + `[xp]`, `[xp]`, `[winxp]`

**`[windows-7]`**: `[windows7]`, `[windows]` + `[7]`, `[win7]`, `[windows-7-api]`

Comment: @3chars: I was a bit lazy adding the Mac stuff to this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41365/tag-merge-request-os-x-related-tags-on-so

Comment: @Jon: Ah, didn't see that one - just added the ones i regularly stumbled upon.

Comment: Note [i-os] does not exist in SO yet, and I lack the rep to make it, but it is the official new name as of a day or two ago of what was formerly called the iPhone OS (even though it is also used in iPods and iPads).

Comment: The official new name of iPhone OS ([iphone-os]) is iOS, not i-OS, so I think the tag should be [ios] instead of [i-os]. Also, I think [ios4] looks better than [ios-4], and it looks like others agree with me, as at the moment of writing there are 240 questions tagged [ios4] and only 1 tagged [ios-4]. So I propose **[ios]** and **[ios*]**

Answer (score 2):

### Database

---

**`[berkeley-db]`**: `[bdb]`, `[berkeleydb]`
**`[berkeley-db-je]`**: `[bdbje]`, `[berkeleydbje]`, `[berkeleydb-je]`

**`[clustered-index]`**: `[clustered-indexing]`, `[clustered]` + `[index]`, `[clustered]` + `[indexing]`

**`[common-table-expression]`**: `[cte]`, `[commontableexpression]`
**`[composite-primary-key]`**: `[multiple-primary-keys]`

**`[database]`**: `[databases]`

**`[database-connection]`**: `[database-connections]`, `[databaseconnection]`, `[database-connectivity]`

**`[data-warehouse]`**: `[data-warehousing]`, `[datawarehousing]`, `[datawarehouse]`

**`[embedded-database]`**: `[embedded-db]`

**`[object-relational-mapping]`**: `[orm]`

**`[oracle-xe]`**: `[oraclexe]`, `[oracle]` + `[xe]`, `[oracle10g-express]`, `[oracle-express]`, `[oracle]`+`[express]`

**`[sql-injection]`**: `[sqlinjection]`, `[sql]` + `[injection]`

**`[sql-server]`**: `[sqlserver]`, `[sql]` + `[server]`, `[mssql]`
**`[sql-server-yyyy]`**: `[sqlserveryyyy]`, `[sql]` + `[server]` + `[yyyy]`, `[mssqlyyyy]`, `[sql-serveryyyy]`
**`[sql-server-express]`**: `[sql-express]`, `[sqlexpress]`, `[sql]` + `[express]`, `[sql]` + `[server]` + `[express]`
**`[sql-server-ce]`**: `[sqlce]`, `[sqlcompact]`, `[sql-compact]`, `[sql-server-compact]`, `[sql-mobile]`

**`[star-schema]`**: `[starschema]`

**`[stored-procedures]`**: `[stored-procedure]`, `[sproc]`, `[stored]` + `[procedure]`, `[stored]` + `[procedures]`

**`[subquery]`**: `[subqueries]`

**`[table-valued-functions]`**: `[table-value-function]`, `[table-value-functions]`, `[table-valued-function]`

**`[tsql]`**: `[t-sql]`, `[transact-sql]`

Comment: @Donal: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45502/so-tag-merge-request-sqlite-and-sqlite3

Comment: @Jon: Damn few people use any version of SQLite prior to 3. That's been the production release since 2004. (According to http://www.sqlite.org/oldnews.html)

Comment: @Donal: In the comments of my answer in that question, the best argument to keep the version 3 tag is for the future (say, version 4 is released) -- if the version 3 tag is eliminated, that would make the base tag ambiguous. In this case I think it's best to maintain the status quo and not *lose* information. Generally speaking `[sqlite3]` *does* imply `[sqlite]`, but the reverse is not true.

Comment: @Jon: You're being too bloody general. We don't know whether there will *ever* be an SQLite4. So apply YAGNI and worry about that problem only when it happens, not before.

Comment: @Donal: Since you have so much to say on the subject, please add an answer to the question I linked to above.

Comment: @Jon: I've been examining what exactly has what tag, and I've changed my mind. I think it might be best to go with `[sqlite]` for the database/library, and `[sqlite3]` for the command line tool. Except there's a lot of mess with the latter tag being used for a lot of other things too; cleaning this up is going to have to be a long-term project of mine. :-(

Comment: @Donal: Why not open a discussion question about that, no need to discuss it here in the comments.

Comment: @3chars: He added an answer to the question I linked to, as I mentioned.

Comment: @APC: I don't understand how those Oracle tags could possibly be synonyms. See the SQL Server tags here. I also rolled back the `[procedure]` tag because that doesn't necessarily apply to stored procedures (it may, but it's an ambiguous tag currently).

Comment: @JonSeigel - Sorry.  I obviously missed the concept of "synonym" here.  The problem is, if I search for [Oracle] I would want to pick up threads which have been tagged [Oracle10g] or [Oracle9i] but not [Oracle] itself.  Because most questions tagged [Oracle10g] actually apply to any (modern) version of Oracle DB. That is I would like tag inheritance.  I guess the same is true of [SQL-Server-2005] etc and [SQL-Server]  I suppose that's a different feature.

Comment: @APC: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle10g%20or%20oracle11g%20or%20oracle9i%20or%20oracle8i

Comment: @JonSeigel - thanks but what I really need is something that works with Interesting Tags ...

Comment: @APC: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34974/have-interesting-tags-that-are-combinations-of-tags

Comment: @JonSeigel - truly you are the Daddy when it comes to tags!

Comment: @JonSeigel - actually that doesn't quite solve my problem.  oracle+oracle10g finds threads which have both tags.  What I want is an Interesting Tag implementation which finds questions with either tag.  In fact what I would want is a mega Interesting Tag which finds question marked oracle|oracle10g|oracle9i|oracle11g|oracle8i|oraclexe|oracle-xe

 ... Perhaps I should ask this as a question

Comment: @APC: My second response was a bit misleading -- what you're asking for is still pending as a feature request. ;) In your position, I'd probably use the search mechanism and keep a bookmark.

Answer (score 2):

### Adobe

---

**`[actionscript-3]`**: `[as3]`
**`[actionscript-2]`**: `[as2]` (needs manual sorting)

**`[flex]`**: `[adobe-flex]`
**`[flex-2]`**: `[flex2]`, `[adobe-flex-2]`
**`[flex-3]`**: `[flex3]`, `[adobe-flex-3]`
**`[flex-4]`**: `[flex4]`, `[adobe-flex-4]`

**`[flex-builder]`**: `[flexbuilder]`

Comment: So this has definitely won against `flex` for meaning lexer? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23959

Comment: @Konrad, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50668/retag-request-flex, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26460/tag-for-two-flexes. General consensus appears to be that Adobe Flex should have the `[flex]` tag, while lexer gets `[gnu-flex]`.

Comment: Yes, I’ve found them myself. And boy does this suck. Nothing against Adobe and all, but `gnu-flex` is simply incorrect, and [Paul is right with what he said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23959/whats-this-about-labelled-tags/24014#24014) … admittedly, that’s neither here nor there and it’s not your fault. The fact remains that choosing a tag just because a product is more popular *at the moment* is flawed at every level …

Comment: @Konrad: I don't make the rules, I'm just going by them :) `[flex]` is a sponsored tag by Adobe, so unless the higher-ups change that, I think Flex it is! Though I would otherwise agree that first come, first served would be best.

Answer (score 2):

### Automated queries

---

- [Singular/Plural duplicates](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/204/singular-plural-duplicate-tags)

Except anomalies such as **c/cs** and **http/https**.

Comment: Very nice! This won't catch all of the singular/plurals because of weird English endings (es, ies, etc.), but it's a good start.

Answer (score 1):

### Web Browsers

---

**`[firefox-2]`**: `[firefox2]`
**`[firefox-3]`**: `[firefox3]`
**`[firefox-3.5]`**: `[firefox3.5]`
**`[firefox-3.5.1]`**: `[firefox3.5.1]`
**`[firefox-3.6]`**: `[firefox3.6]`

**`[google-chrome]`**: `[chrome]`

**`[internet-explorer]`**: `[ie]`, `[internet]` + `[explorer]`
**`[internet-explorer-6]`**: `[ie6]`, `[ie-6]`, `[internet-explorer6]`
**`[internet-explorer-7]`**: `[ie7]`, `[ie-7]`, `[internet-explorer7]`
**`[internet-explorer-8]`**: `[ie8]`, `[ie-8]`, `[internet-explorer8]`
**`[internet-explorer-9]`**: `[ie9]`, `[ie-8]`, `[internet-explorer9]`

Answer (score 1):

### Other Programming Languages

---

**`[go]`**: `[golang]`, `[go-language]`

**`[javascript]`**: `[java-script]`, `[js]`, `[java]` + `[script]` (needs manual sorting)

**`[python3]`**: `[python-3.x]`, `[python-3.1]`

**`[ruby-on-rails]`**: `[rails]`
**`[ruby-on-rails-3]`**: `[ruby-on-rails3]`, `[rails3]`
**`[ruby-on-rails-3-beta]`**: `[ruby-on-rails3beta]`

Answer (score 1):

### International English

---

-A-

**`[analog]`**: `[analogue]`

**`[analysis]`**: `[analyze]`, `[analyse]`

**`[artifacts]`**: `[artefacts]`, `[artifact]`, `[artefact]`

**`[authority]`**: `[authorize]`, `[authorise]`, `[authorizing]`, `[authorising]`, `[unauthorized]`, `[unauthorised]`

-B-

**`[behavior]`**: `[behaviour]`, `[behaviors]`, `[behaviours]`

**`[best-practices]`**: `[best-practice]`, `[best-practise]`, `[best-practices]`, `[best-practises]`, `[best]` + `[practice]`, `[best]` + `[practise]`, `[best]` + `[practices]` `[best]` + `[practises]`, `[best]` ***Should `[practice]` be merged with this? Should there be/is there a `[worst-practice]` tag?***

-C-

**`[capitalization]`**: `[capitalisation]`, `[capitalize]`, `[capitalise]`, `[capitalized]`, `[capitalised]`, `[capitalizes]`, `[capitalises]`, `[capitalizing]`, `[capitalising]`

**`[cancel]`**: `[canceled]`, `[cancelled]`, `[canceling]`, `[cancelling]`

**`[cataloging]`**: `[cataloguing]`, `[catalog]`, `[catalogue]`, `[cataloged]`, `[catalogued]`, `[catalogs]`, `[catalogues]`

**`[categorizing]`**: `[categorising]`, `[categorize]`, `[categorise]`, `[categorized]`, `[categorised]`, `[categorizes]`. `[categorises]`

**`[center]`**: `[centre]`, `[centers]`, `[centres]`

**`[color]`**: `[colour]`, `[colors]`, `[colours]`

**`[connection]`**: `[connexion]`, `[connections]`, `[connexions]`

**`[customization]`**: `[customisation]`, `[customize]`, `[customise]`, `[customized]`, `[customised]`, `[customizes]`, `[customises]`, `[customizing]`, `[customising]`

**`[cipher]`**: `[cypher]`, `[ciphers]`, `[cyphers]`

-D-

**`[defensive]`**: `[defencive]`, `[defense]`, `[defence]`, `[defenses]`, `[defences]`

**`[dialogs]`**: `[dialogues]`, `[dialog]`, `[dialogue]`

**`[digitizing]`**: `[digitising]`, `[digitize]`, `[digitise]`, `[digitized]`, `[digitised]`, `[digitizes]`, `[digitises]`

**`[disk]`**: `[disc]`, `[disks]`, `[discs]` ***Is the word disc used in the US for CDs and DVDs? If so, then we need separate `[disk]`: `[disks]` and `[disc]`: `[discs]`***

-E-

**`[equalization]`**: `[equalisation]`, `[equalize]`, `[equalise]`, `[equalized]`, `[equalised]`, `[equalizer]`, `[equaliser]`, `[equalizers]`, `[equalisers]`, `[equalizes]`, `[equalises]`, `[equalizing]`, `[equalising]`

**`[esthetics]`**: `[aesthetics]`

**`[evangelizing]`**: `[evangelising]`

**`[externalizing]`**: `[externalising]`

-F-

**`[factorizing]`**: `[factorising]`, `[factorize]`, `[factorise]`, `[factorized]`, `[factorised]`, `[factorizes]`, `[factorises]`

**`[fiber]`**: `[fibre]`, `[fibers]`, `[fibres]`

**`[finalization]`**: `[finalisation]`, `[finalize]`, `[finalise]`, `[finalized]`, `[finalised]`, `[finalizes]`, `[finalises]`, `[finalizing]`, `[finalising]`

-G-

**`[globalization]`**: `[globalisation]`, `[globalize]`, `[globalise]`, `[globalized]`, `[globalised]`, `[globalizes]`, `[globalises]`, `[globalizing]`, `[globalising]` ***Should these be merged with localization?***

**`[gluing]`**: `[glueing]`

**`[gray]`**: `[grey]`, `[grayed]`, `[greyed]`, `[graying]`, `[greying]`, `[grayish]`, `[greyish]`, `[grayness]` `[greyness]`, `[grays]`, `[greys]`

-H-

**`[humanizing]`**: `[humanising]`, `[humanize]`, `[humanise]`, `[humanized]`, `[humanised]`, `[humanizes]`, `[humanises]`

**`[humor]`**: `[humour]`

-I-

**`[image]`**: `[images]`

**`[install]`**: `[installs]`, `[instals]`

**`[italicizing]`**: `[italicising]`, `[italicize]`, `[italicise]`, `[italicized]`, `[italicised]`, `[italicizes]`, `[italicises]`

-J-

-K-

-L-

**`[labels]`**: `[labeled]`, `[labelled]`, `[labeling]`, `[labelling]`

**`[localization]`**: `[localisation]`, `[localize]`, `[localise]`, `[localized]`, `[localised]`, `[localizes]`, `[localises]`, `[localizing]`, `[localising]` ***Should these be merged with globalization?***

-M-

**`[miter]`**: `[mitre]`, `[miters]`, `[mitres]`

**`[modeling]`**: `[modelling]`, `[modeled]`, `[modelled]`, `[modeler]`, `[modeller]`, `[modelers]`, `[modellers]`

-N-

**`[neighbors]`**: `[neighbours]`, `[neighbor]`, `[neighbour]`, `[neighborhood]`, `[neighbourhood]`, `[neighborhoods]`, `[neighbourhoods]`, `[neighboring]`, `[neighbouring]`, `[neighborliness]`, `[neighbourliness]`, `[neighborly]`, `[neighbourly]`

**`[normalization]`**: `[normalisation]`, `[normalize]`, `[normalise]`, `[normalized]`, `[normalised]`, `[normalizes]`, `[normalises]`, `[normalizing]`, `[normalising]`

-O-

**`[optimization]`**: `[optimisation]`, `[optimize]`, `[optimise]`, `[optimized]`, `[optimised]`, `[optimizes]`, `[optimises]`, `[optimizing]`, `[optimising]`

**`[organization]`**: `[organisation]`, `[organize]`, `[organise]`, `[organized]`, `[organised]`, `[organizer]`, `[organiser]`, `[organizers]`, `[organisers]`, `[organizes]`, `[organises]`, `[organizing]`, `[organising]`

-P-

**`[panels]`**: `[paneled]`, `[panelled]`, `[paneling]`, `[panelling]`, `[panelist]`, `[panellist]`, `[panelists]`, `[panellists]`

**`[personalization]`**: `[personalisation]`, `[personalize]`, `[personalise]`, `[personalized]`, `[personalised]`, `[personalizes]`, `[personalises]`, `[personalizing]`, `[personalising]`

**`[philosophy]`**: `[philosophize]`, `[philosophise]`, `[philosophized]`, `[philosophised]`, `[philosophizes]`, `[philosophises]`, `[philosophizing]`, `[philosophising]`

**`[Plagiarism]`**: `[plagiarize]`, `[plagiarise]`, `[plagiarized]`, `[plagiarised]`, `[plagiarizes]` `[plagiarises]`, `[plagiarizing]`, `[plagiarising]` ***If we are keeping this one, can someone add in `[plagarizm]` if that is a real word please? I am not familiar enough with US spelling to be sure.***

**`[practice]`**: `[practise]`, `[practiced]`, `[practised]`, `[practices]`, `[practises]`, `[practicing]`, `[practising]` ***Should this be merged with `[best-practice]`?***

**`[priority]`**: `[prioritization]`, `[prioritisation]`, `[prioritize]`, `[prioritise]`, `[prioritized]`, `[prioritised]`, `[prioritizes]`, `[prioritises]`, `[prioritizing]`, `[prioritising]`

**`[programs]`**: `[programmes]`, `[program]`, `[programme]`

**`[publicity]`**: `[publicizing]`, `[publicising]`, `[publicize]`, `[publicise]`, `[publicized]`, `[publicised]`, `[publicizes]`, `[publicises]`, `[publicizing]`, `[publicising]`

-Q-

-R-

**`[randomness]`**: `[randomization]`, `[randomisation]`, `[randomize]`, `[randomise]`, `[randomized]`, `[randomised]`, `[randomizes]`, `[randomises]`, `[randomizing]`, `[randomising]`

**`[reorganization]`**: `[reorganisation]`, `[reorganizations]`, `[reorganisations]`, `[reorganize]`, `[reorganise]`, `[reorganized]`, `[reorganised]`, `[reorganizes]`, `[reorganises]`, `[reorganizing]`, `[reorganising]`

**`[rumor]`**: `[rumour]`, `[rumored]`, `[rumoured]`, `[rumors]`, `[rumours]`

-S-

**`[sanitizing]`**: `[sanitising]`, `[sanitize]`, `[sanitise]`, `[sanitized]`, `[sanitised]`, `[sanitizes]`, `[sanitises]`

**`[social]`**: `[socialization]`, `[socialisation]`, `[socialize]`, `[socialise]`, `[socialized]`, `[socialised]`, `[socializes]`, `[socialises]`, `[socializing]`, `[socialising]`

**`[stability]`**: `[stabilization]`, `[stabilisation]`, `[stabilize]`, `[stabilise]`, `[stabilized]`, `[stabilised]`, `[stabilizer]`, `[stabiliser]`, `[stabilizes]`, `[stabilises]`, `[stabilizers]`, `[stabilisers]`, `[stabilizes]`, `[stabilises]`, `[stabilizing]`, `[stabilising]`

**`[standards]`**: `[standardization]`, `[standardisation]`, `[standardize]`, `[standardise]`, `[standardized]`, `[standardised]`, `[standardizes]`, `[standardises]`, `[standardizing]`, `[standardising]`

**`[summarizing]`**: `[summarising]`, `[summarize]`, `[summarise]`, `[summarized]`, `[summarised]`, `[summarizes]`, `[summarises]`, `[summary]`

**`[symbols]`**: `[symbolize]`, `[symbolise]`, `[symbolized]`, `[symbolised]`, `[symbolizes]`, `[symbolises]`, `[symbolizing]`, `[symbolising]`

**`[synchronization]`**: `[synchronisation]`, `[synchronize]`, `[synchronise]`, `[synchronized]`, `[synchronised]`, `[synchronizes]`, `[synchronises]`, `[synchronizing]`, `[synchronising]`

**`[synthesis]`**: `[synthesize]`, `[synthesise]`, `[synthesized]`, `[synthesised]`, `[synthesizer]`, `[synthesiser]`, `[synthesizers]`, `[synthesisers]`, `[synthesizes]`, `[synthesises]`, `[synthesizing]`, `[synthesising]`

-T-

**`[text-to-speech]`**: `[verbalization]`, `[verbalisation]`, `[verbalize]`, `[verbalise]`, `[verbalized]`, `[verbalised]`, `[verbalizes]`, `[verbalises]`, `[verbalizing]`, `[verbalising]`, `[vocalization]`, `[vocalisation]`, `[vocalizations]`, `[vocalisations]`, `[vocalize]`, `[vocalise]`, `[vocalized]`, `[vocalised]`, `[vocalizes]`, `[vocalises]`, `[vocalizing]`, `[vocalising]`

**`[trials]`**: `[trialed]`, `[trialled]`, `[trialing]`, `[trialling]`

**`[tunneling]`**: `[tunnelling]`, `[tunneled]`, `[tunnelled]`

-U-

**`[utilization]`**: `[utilisation]`, `[utilizable]`, `[utilisable]`, `[utilize]`, `[utilise]`, `[utilized]`, `[utilised]`, `[utilizes]`, `[utilises]`, `[utilizing]`, `[utilising]`

-V-

**`[virtualization]`**: `[virtualisation]`, `[virtualizations]`, `[virtualisations]`, `[virtualize]`, `[virtualise]`, `[virtualized]`, `[virtualised]`, `[virtualizes]`, `[virtualises]`, `[virtualizing]`, `[virtualising]`

**`[visualization]`**: `[visualisation]`, `[visualizations]`, `[visualisations]`, `[visualize]`, `[visualise]`, `[visualized]`, `[visualised]`, `[visualizes]`, `[visualises]`, `[visualizing]`, `[visualising]`

-W-

-X-

-Y-

-Z-

Comment: It is possible that these should just go in the Miscellaneous section. Indeed, color, with additiional plurals, altready is, but I have put it here as well for editing/discussion of the idea of "International English" as a seperate heading.

Comment: There is a list of some 1700 alternately spelt general words here: http://www.tysto.com/articles05/q1/20050324uk-us.shtml . I don't have time today, but I plan to go through the list looking for relevant ones and post them here.

Comment: OK, I have added lots of words. I have definitely erred on the side of including extra words rather than leaving out any possibles; I fully expect many to be edited out :)

Comment: Note that some words do not directly have alternate spellings, but some of their possible alternatives do; e.g. [standards].

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I'll address some of the interpost commetary later today. Could you please prune the list to only include synonyms that already exist on SOFU? We don't need to include more than that in this repository. Thanks.

Comment: Is there an easy way to determine if a given word already exists as a tag in the trilogy? I wonder if resident Python charmer @The Cat might kindly take on automating this? I'd be manually doing it, and I won't have that sort of time for a few days.

Comment: The following tags and all of the suggested synonyms do not exist at all on all parts of the trilogy: biasing, commercialization, computerization, conceptualizing, decentralization, destabilization, economizing, encyclopedia, enrollment, familiarization, generalization, hybridizing, itemizing, labor, legalization, modernization, neutralization, penalties, polarization, popularization, rationalization, rigor, rigors, skepticism, signaling, socialism, systemizing, tricolor, vaporware

Comment: The following tags exist on the sites that mean roughly what you suggest, but not in the parent tag or any synonym you suggested. The word in parentheses is the tag you suggested as the parent. italicize (italicizing), equalizer (equalization), catalog (cataloging), categorization (categorizing), factorization (factorizing), glue (gluing), humanize (humanizing), publicize (publicity), reorganize (reorganization), sanitization (sanitizing), summarization/summary (summarizing)

Comment: Lastly, "defensive" doesn't exist as a standalone tag (it's a dependent-adjective ambiguous tag so big minus there), but there are some related tags like defensive-programming. All other tags exist, either as the root tag or one of the suggested synonyms or as a plural/singular difference, on at least one of the sites. The majority of tags you listed that were not tags were words that ended in -ing or -ation.

Comment: Awesome - thanks @ccomet! Still happy for anyone to do the required editing, but if no-one else does I will get to it in a couple of days.

Comment: On another note, one interesting aspect of internationalising tags is that often neither is wrong. Some of the tag synonym proposals out there suggest that the undividual user could choose their preference of color/colour, for example, and have everything seamlessly map. One possible syntax to represent this 'both are right' situation here might be **`[color]`, `[colour]`**: `[colors]`, `[colours]`. Thoughts?

Comment: That would complicate the system far too much. The generally accepted practice right now is for everything to be in American English, so those should be chosen as the master tags. @ccomet: Thanks for going through those. Also, @whybird: since these comments are on your answer, if you want to ping me, you'll need to use @Jon in your comments. Thanks.

Comment: @Jon - Agree. I'm fine with that, so long as my natural spellings get translated properly when I try to enter them.

Comment: Note: I have added [virtualization] since @ccomet's analysis. This comment is just a reminder to self or other editor to check that one later.

Comment: virtualization is present on at least one of the sites.

Comment: Took care of part of the editing, specifically all the terms that do not exist at all. Regarding capitalization, you grouped it with commercialization, but I'm pretty sure any question on the sites that has to do with capitalization has less to do with commerce as it does typography.

Comment: @ccomet awesome again - thanks. Yes, good call re: capititalization.

Comment: @Jon, you asked that synonyms that don't yet exist be removed. If I am interpreting what you said correctly, I disagree on the basis that prevention is better than cure. If someone types, say, 'artefact' as a potential tag and it doesn't exist, we want the system to give them 'aritfacts' rather than creating a new tag.

Comment: @whybird: Agreed. However, this is not meant to be a fully complete dictionary or thesaurus of corrections (of which there are nearly infinite). It's also difficult to predict how a tag will be used in the future -- it could be the name of a product, or it could end up being ambiguous -- we just don't know yet. This repository was meant more to cover the extremely popular tags, so when searching, all relevant material is grouped together. New tags can be corrected if users pay attention to the 10k tools -- there is a list of newly created tags in there, and misspellings are easy to spot.

Comment: @Jon: Agreed that a complete list of corrections is impossible, however this particular area is not one of misspellings, and can be fairly fully predicted. 'artefact' is not wrong, but should always be grouped with 'artifacts'. Also it is highly unlikely that anyone will make a product known by an English word with a US equavalent, for the same reason that we agree to use the US spelling as the standard here. (continued next comment)

Comment: Suggest that in the unlikely event of that happening, the list could be changed then. Meanwhile, the common case of simply spelling something correctly but alternately to the accepted version here can be automaitacilly corrected. Having said that, I can see that having all derivitaves of a word (eg [symbolizing]/[symbolising] mapping to [symbols]) is probably unnecessary and undesirable.

Comment: p.s. I am unaware of what 10k tools exist; good info there, thanks.

Comment: @whybird: Okay, I agree. I will hopefully find some time this weekend to go through the list here.

Answer (score 0):

### Microsoft Office

---

**`[excel]`**: `[microsoft-excel]`, `[ms-excel]`
**`[excel-yyyy]`**: `[microsoft-excel-yyyy]`, `[excelyyyy]`, `[excel-yy]`, `[excelyy]`

**`[microsoft-access]`**: `[ms-access]`, `[access]`
**`[microsoft-access-yyyy]`**: `[ms-access-yyyy]`, `[ms-access-yy]`, `[access-yyyy]`, `[access-yy]`

**`[microsoft-office]`**: `[ms-office]`, `[office]` (needs hand-separating)
**`[microsoft-office-yyyy]`**: `[ms-office-yyyy]`, `[ms-office-yy]`, `[office-yyyy]`, `[office-yy]`, `[officeyyyy]`, `[officeyy]`

**`[microsoft-word]`**: `[msword]`, `[word]` (needs hand-separating), `[wordyy]`, `[wordyyyy]`
**`[microsoft-word-yyyy]`**: `[mswordyyyy]`, `[mswordyy]`, `[msword-yyyy]`, `[msword-yy]`, `[word-yyyy]`, `[word-yy]`

**`[outlook]`**: `[microsoft-office-outlook]`
**`[outlook-yyyy]`**: `[outlookyyyy]`
**`[outlook-addin]`**: `[outlook-plugin]`, `[outlook]` + `[addin]`, `[outlook]` + `[plugin]`

**`[powerpoint]`**: `[microsoft-powerpoint]`, `[ms-powerpoint]`
**`[powerpoint-yyyy]`**: `[powerpointyyyy]`, `[powerpointyy]`

**`[redemption]`**: `[outlook-redemption]`

Comment: Is this one for SuperUser, or do they need added on SO as well?

Comment: @Bill: Both. Probably moreso on SO since the volume is higher.

Answer (score 0):

### Meta Stack Overflow

---

**`[allowed-topics]`**: `[where-to-post]`
**`[answers]`**: `[answer]`
**`[associated-accounts]`**: `[linked-accounts]`, `[related-accounts]`

**`[badges]`**: `[badge]`
**`[badge-description]`**: `[badge-text]`

**`[captcha]`**: `[human-verification]`

**`[exact-duplicates]`**: `[duplicates]`

**`[links]`**: `[link]`, `[hyperlink]`, `[hyperlinks]`

**`[new-users]`**: `[new-user]`

**`[profile-page]`**: `[user-page]`

**`[questions]`**: `[question]`

**`[recent-envelope]`**: `[magic-envelope]`
**`[reputation-audit]`**: `[reputation-report]`
**`[reputation-recalculation]`**: `[reputation-recalc]`, `[rep-recalc]`, `[rep-recalculation]`
**`[revisions-list]`**: `[edit-history]`, `[revision-list]`

**`[search]`**: `[searching]`
**`[split-vote-count]`**: `[vote-count]`, `[vote-details]`, `[vote-totals]`

**`[users]`**: `[user]`
**`[user-accounts]`**: `[accounts]`, `[user-account]`
**`[user-interface]`**: `[ui]`
**`[user-profiles]`**: `[profile]`, `[profiles]`, `[user-profile]`

Comment: Hey @Jon, wondering why you removed my [tags]: [tagging] addition here? Perhaps I misunderstand their use, but I thought they'd be prime candidates.

Comment: @whybird See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48017/tag-etiquette-gerunds-versus-plurals-or-tagging-vs-tags