# Tag synonym entry errors on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

First, I have to give HUGE props to Bill the Lizard for taking the time to put in a TON of [tag synonyms on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms)! Judging by the rename counts of the first ones put in the system, the synonyms are definitely working.

I was going through the list, and I saw several tags with ending brackets ( ] ). I'm assuming these are entry errors due to typing [tag], because we're all used to doing that.

Here are the ones I found:

weblogic-9]
teamsystem]
picture]
timezones]
timezoneinfo]
web.config]
transact-sql]
google-chrome-os]  (source tag)
.hgignore]
ruby-on-rails3beta]

Going on my assumption of the cause of the problem, I'm piggy-backing a bug fix request on here to get Sam or Jeff to make sure invalid tag characters are stripped from the user input in the moderator UI. Or, if this is in fact a system problem, it needs a bit of investigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, props go to you guys for making the [Official repository of tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms). I scraped a bunch of text from that page and converted it to SQL scripts for the devs to run. The bug was in my script. Thanks to everyone involved in that, it's a downright intimidating amount of information. (I'll go fix those errors manually now.)