# Mention the rep required to edit tag synonyms in the FAQ

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms, faq-update-request

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57479/allowing-users-with-a-nominal-amount-of-rep-to-submit-possible-tag-synonyms-and-v/57983#57983) states that the minimum rep is **2000**, but you have to search around to find this. I suggest listing it in the FAQ page.

Comment: Especially because it's not 2000 rep all over the board (it's 1000 on public betas.)

Comment: I think this should wait until tag wikis are a complete feature (history/time line etc) before looking at adding it to the FAQ

Comment: UPDATE: yerp I think its time to include this stuff in the FAQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done quite a while ago: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms

Answer (score 0):

While not the solution you were looking for, this is included on the [synonyms page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/data-explorer/synonyms):

> Users with more than 2000 reputation can suggest and vote on tag synonyms.

Since this is on exactly the page in which it matters, you'd have to search even less than if it was only in the FAQ.  The FAQ deals with the site in a very broad way, and I don't see the need to introduce all users (especially new users) to this detail.  However, mentioning something about synonyms in the FAQ (even just a link to an announcement or otherwise) would be useful.

(I don't know if this was shown on the synonyms page when you posted this question, or if it was later updated.)