# Rep required for voting on tag synonyms is much lower than 2000

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-synonyms, documentation

All the current documentation for tag synonyms imply (or [even](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared) [state](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57479)) 2000 is needed to *vote* on tag synonyms. Unless it is a beta-test issue or something, I can vote on synonyms with <700 on SO and <730 on Meta. (I cannot vote in SU with 130 odd or StackApps with 140.)

Comment: Please note that my question is not official in any way. :)

Comment: @badp Note my alt-text for the link to your question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial implementation and unit tests all had tag editing as the rep requirement. I just upped it to post editing cause I think it makes much more sense.

Synonyms can be pretty destructive.

Comment: I think I understand your response: Voting required the same rep as tag editing and now you've made it the same rep requirement as post editing. I assume it takes a while for your changes to go live -- I can still vote on SO and MSO.

Comment: yerp, note this will be in the next deploy, probably early next week

Comment: It probably makes sense to lower the bar to start with anyway, to clear most of the older clearly reasonable synonyms.