# Prune or merge useless tags

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

StackOverflow currently has well in excess of 30000 [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags). But even on [page 100](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=100&tab=popular) out of 852 there appear to be extremely few questions.

Is there a general mechanism to review and revise existing tags? I'm noticing that there are many tags for specific data structures within specific languages; wouldn't it make sense to coalesce all those into a few, general tags for that language? Ultimately, if you tag your question as `c++_unique_ptr`, you're almost surely going to tag it as [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) as well.

By not offering too many specific tags we encourage people to add all the appropriate general tags without getting bogged down. And reversely it is already the case that lots of lesser-quality questions with general tags are lacking the specific tags that would apply, but end up getting answered anyway.

Removing overly specific tags is one way to clean up. Another way that comes to mind is to de-separate version-specific tags (if that makes sense), but I have no opinion on whether version-specific tags are currently useful. Finally, there are some bogus tags like [templates](/questions/tagged/templates) which isn't helping anyone because it subsumes Perl HTML templates and C++ templates. If the tag can't be used meaningfully, do we need it?

Enough with the ranting; the main question is whether there's any mechanized, general process to prune the SO tag soup, and if anyone feels that pruning would be desirable.

Comment: So how, exactly, would we go about creating an automated process to do this? Cleaning up tags is a potentially great idea, but it's one that needs to be done by humans that can read questions, evaluate context, and make decisions. I wouldn't leave this to some kind of script. Just because a tag isn't used by very many questions (~130 on the page you linked to) is not an indication that there's something wrong with the tag. You're likely correct about *specific* examples like [tag:template], but how is a machine going to know when it belongs and what to replace it with--Perl, C++, etc.?

Comment: Well, an assisting machine would be useful: Some magic website where you can drag tags around and see what _would_ happen if you were to change one tag for another... something that lets you explore the consequences of and potential for tag rearrangement. The whole thing could be powered by a hint system where you say `c++_unique_ptr` falls under `c++`, but a human could be processing the hints and check whether any particular merge makes sense.

Comment: Yeah...we don't have that... :-)

Comment: Have you heard about tags synonyms ?

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57479/allowing-users-with-a-nominal-amount-of-rep-to-submit-possible-tag-synonyms-and-v

Comment: @Scorpi0: That's already quite useful. How do I view the collapsed tag collection of SO which suppresses all synonyms and aggregates their statistics into the master tag? [Edit:] Oh, are the synonyms already removed from the main tag collection?

Comment: today i find some useless tag such as "facbook"(Missing 'e' after 'c') and or "asp.netmvc"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the main question is whether there's any mechanized, general process to prune the SO tag soup, and if anyone feels that pruning would be desirable.

See [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418) on the question [Should We Zap The Low-Occurrence Tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags)

> I am convinced this is a useful cleanup task, to remove these orphaned tags from the system automatically. I've implemented a routine that removes tags created more than 6 months ago which have been used only a single time. It will run monthly.

That's the only automated tag pruning that goes on.  Any other tags that need to be removed either need to be set to a synonym of another tag (but only if they literally mean *exactly* the same thing) and merged, or just removed from questions manually.

I'm not sure I agree with your point about coalescing more specific (but still *used*) tags into more general tags.  For every question that gets answered despite not having specific tags, I can find one that *didn't* get answered because it was not tagged appropriately.  There have also been tags that have been used a *lot* but were almost totally useless (`subjective`, `not-programming-related`, `off-topic`), so it would be very difficult to come up with an automated way to judge the *usefulness* of a tag.  In short, I think humans need to keep doing this.

Comment: Alright, that looks very good. So, if we synonymize a tag, does the synonym get removed entirely from the system as far as visible tags are concerned? But I was also wondering about "generalizing" tags that are too specific - those wouldn't be synonyms, but genuine substitutions.

Comment: @Kerrek SB:  The merge still has to be done by a moderator, if I remember correctly.  You can flag a question with the tag that needs merged and let us know that it's a synonym of another tag.

Comment: @Kerrek: See the last paragraph I added for my thoughts on generalizing tags.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to best thread this conversation. Should I have opened a new topic?

Check out the tag [getmodulefilenameex](/questions/tagged/getmodulefilenameex): It is **way** over-specific, and it should be subsumed under "Windows API". However, since it has too low a score, I cannot even propose a synonym. How would one best get rid of such a tag, and why was it created in the first place?

Comment: 1. You should probably just edit this into your original question as an update.  2.  I would say that that tag is too obscure to even propose as a synonym, and I'll re-tag those.  Synonyms are for things that would commonly be used in the place of another tag but needs to be unified under one tag

Comment: Also, indeed, synonyms are really not the right thing for the gripe I've been trying to bring up. This tag here is the true example of what I want to prune: Generalise overly obscure tags upwards into more useful categories that people might actually look for or respond to.

Comment: Uhh, **there are no questions with that tag**. So you don't *need* to get rid of it, or do anything at all with it. It's not being used anywhere on the site.

Comment: Not fair, there were three questions when I asked! :-) But I do would like new users *not* to be able to select "getmodulefilenameex" as a tag -- is that possible?

Comment: Hrm. I don't see anything *wrong* with that tag. Yes, it should obviously be combined with `[winapi]`, but if I want to know about using a relatively common function, I should be able to search all questions with that tag. There is a [tag:setwindowshookex] tag that I think is *quite* useful.

Comment: Hmm... 40 questions in three years? Couldn't that just go under WinApi too, with "Hook" in the question title? I mean, OK, *some* functions may like their own tag, but somehow it feels gratuitous. The nearest library/framework tag above should provide ample charactarisation, don't you think?

Comment: @Cody yes there are none because I re-tagged them (as stated above)

Comment: @Daniel: Weird. Why? What was that tag hurting, and why should we bump a whole bunch of old questions just to remove a tag? If the tag is *bad*, a moderator should ban it, automatically removing it from the questions without leaving an edit history trail.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It could. But with that logic, why not just tag the question [tag:windows]? Or [tag:programming]? The idea is to *categorize* questions. Just because something is asked about relatively infrequently does not make that categorization mechanism any less useful. We don't need to ban or eliminate any of these tags. They all serve the purpose of tags: **accurately categorizing content**. I use it *all the time* in searching questions. I do the same thing with a number of other WinAPI-specific function tags I'm hesitant to reveal here, lest they be removed...

Comment: @Cody: Come on, no reason to be snarky, I'm just trying to help improve SO - of course we won't have a single "programming" tag. But we have tons of "C++" questions which are all well structured and *don't* have sub-tags "for-loops", "overloading" or "partial specialization". There's a hierarchy of specificity going from tags to question title to question body, and the separation is worth making. Categories are very useful, of course. But I'd like to think that a category should identify the field of the question in such a way that a competent practitioner of that field ...

Comment: ... should have a reasonable chance of understanding the question.  That's why I'd like to stop at the most specific library or framework, if that notion applies, and *not* dive into individual functions. If you know the Windows API, you're probably able to help. But would there really be someone who only knows one function well? You see, I think the specificity "function" is something perfectly suited for the question title, but it's too narrow for the category. Hm, I hope that's making sense.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I'm not being snarky. I'm genuinely upset at the idea or reality of having tags like that removed. As I mentioned, I regularly use them to find content. It's not like SO's search system is fantabulous. I have a lot more success searching by tag than I do searching by keyword. I don't understand what those tags were **hurting** by being there. If you aren't interested in them, don't search for them or filter them out. This is not improving SO, this is hurting my experience and ignoring the purpose of tags as categorizers for content.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with a [`method-overloading`] tag or a `[for-loops]` tag. I've added those to questions myself. They help people to find questions concerning topics that they're interested in. Isn't that the point? Yes, there are other parts of the question that can contain that information, but that's irrelevant to the point here. There are a whole bunch of C++ questions that are just tagged with `[c++]`. **That's completely worthless.** I get nearly **80,000** questions when I search that tag. I can't find *anything* that way.

Comment: C++ and the Windows API are very similar. They're both *huge*. It's *not* likely that someone who knows the Windows API can answer any question about it. I know a *lot* about the GUI aspects of the Windows API, but nearly nothing about many of the other wide-ranging aspects. Yes, there are *lots* of people who know one function well, or one aspect well. Templates in C++, for example, or hook functions in the Windows API.

Comment: @Cody: OK, so my reasoning, which I'm merely putting up for discussion and am happy to revise, was that having too many tags (30000+) is actually detrimental, because it fragments the questions and makes it harder to spot what's worth reading, especially given the 5-tag limit. Rather than having five appropriate high-level tags, you sometimes get lots of very specific tags and thus might miss out on attracting a whole range or other competent readers. If it didn't come at the price of missing out on higher-level tags, I'd probably not even worry, and finding specific things is indeed nice.

Comment: @Kerrek: There are *very few* questions that use up all 5 tags. I don't think there's any real problem here that needs to be solved, other than encouraging users to use *more* tags with their questions. If you want to search for everything contained within the Windows API, then use the existing `[winapi]` tag. If I want something more specific, I'll use another tag. Since questions about WinAPI hooks include *both* tags, everything works out. There's nothing wrong with a lot of tags other than a "Tags" page with many sub-pages. But that doesn't really hurt anyone.

Comment: The only thing wrong with a lot of tags is the possibility of *redundancy* within those tags. But tag synonyms fix that problem quite well, and if you don't have the requisite rep, post a question on meta regarding that specific tag. Someone with the rep, or a moderator, will come along and fix the problem. But tags that add sub-levels of categorization are *not* redundant and therefore not a problem.

Comment: @Cody: You make some good points. Let me think about this again. Somehow I don't feel that having soo many tags is The Right Thing, but you're right that it probably doesn't do harm for the time being.

Comment: @Cody 3 questions on the tag in 3 years, and I'm typically not a huge fan of method name tags though I wouldn't retag those that have a large question base already.  If you're looking for a question about a specific method the normal search methods would work; nobody was "following" the tag and I can't imagine too many folks had it as an interesting tag

Comment: @Daniel: I quite disagree. As mentioned, there's no use in bumping old questions just to remove tags. Those tags weren't hurting anyone. You can't accurately gauge the usefulness of tags based on the number of people following them. I don't "follow" tags, although I do use them extensively. There are quite a few other tags that are only used by a few questions, but there's no reason to assume that they're "bad" tags any more so than they cover topics/subjects that just *aren't very popular*. I don't understand the crusade making it harder to find questions about unpopular material.

Comment: The point is, once again, *it wasn't a bad tag*. There are a lot of low-frequency tags that *are* bad tags because they don't serve the purpose of usefully categorizing content. But that done *did*, as do all tags that are specific to a particular method or function call. And if it *is* a bad tag, then we have better ways of dealing with this type of thing than manual retags. But please don't conflate low-frequency with useless.

Comment: I see nothing wronge with the getmodulefilenameex tag, provided anyone that searches for the Windows API tag also finds the question.   The issue is that we have no way to always force the "parent" tag to be put on a question as well as the "child" tag.