# How should versioned jQuery tags be combined on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request

I was looking at jQuery related tags and noticed the last two major versions account for five separate tags:  [jquery1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery1.3) (32), [jquery1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery1.4) (18), [jquery1.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery1.3.2) (8), [jquery-1.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.3.2) (4) and [jquery-1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.4) (3)

Since the [Official repository of tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms) seems to the `product-x.y` format, I would suggest merging into `jquery-1.3` and `jquery-1.4`, but I wanted to open for discussion.  Also, should this be added to the tag synonyms list?

Answer (score 2):

Update: I removed the [jquery-1.4](/questions/tagged/jquery-1.4) -> [jquery1.4](/questions/tagged/jquery1.4) synonym, since this was backwards compared to most other thing-major.minor tag formats.  Also I reversed my earlier analysis (left below for reference), the questions (< 10) tagged with the jQuery minor-minor releases just didn't justify keeping those tags, they're now under [jquery-1.4](/questions/tagged/jquery-1.4).

Also, I [added a reverse synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-1.4/synonyms) in place, [jquery1.4](/questions/tagged/jquery1.4) -> [jquery-1.4](/questions/tagged/jquery-1.4) which is the correct version format for tags.

---

I would recommend **against** merging the minor releases, there are issues in each release, for example a common question is about the `change` event not bubbling in IE (causing `.live('change', func)` breaks).  This issue is specific to 1.4.1 and fixed in 1.4.2 (along with many event questions).

I would recommend mapping:

- [jquery1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery1.3) (32) -> [jquery-1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.3)
- [jquery1.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery1.3.2) (8) -> [jquery-1.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.3.2)
- [jquery1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery1.4) (18), [jquery14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery14) (2) -> [jquery-1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.4)
- [jquery1.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery1.4.1) (1) -> [jquery-1.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.4.1)
- [jquery1.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery1.4.2) (8) -> [jquery-1.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.4.2)

Personally I would leave the minor releases intact, this would result in [jquery-1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.3), [jquery-1.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.3.2), [jquery 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.4), [jquery 1.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.4.1), and [jquery 1.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.4.2).

That being said, leaving only [jquery-1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.3) and [jquery-1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.4) wouldn't be all that bad, but the vast majority of questions aren't tagged with a version at all (something I'll start doing in future edits).

---

*Update:* I moved the jquery1.x.x tags to jquery-1.x.x to at least normalize the formatting for now, there are still a number of jquery1.3 and jquery1.4 out there that need a bulk retag.

Comment: Why would we merge jquery14 with jquery1.4?
I thought we wanted to keep major releases separate.

Comment: @devinb - jQuery14 *is* 1.4...1.4 is the latest release, there's no jQuery 14 out there :)

Comment: I see your point about minor versions affecting the question, but doesn't this better fit in the question text and not the tag?

Comment: @Kevin - *I* don't think so, my opinion again of course...when I see certain issues I would immediately recognize the issue as a known bug in that version, I would tag questions with those issues with that minor version as well...to indicate it's specific to `jQuery-1.4.1` Often the issue doesn't apply to `jQuery-1.4` overall, and *most* people being on the latest (of 1.4 users) wouldn't be affected.  That being said, I may be one of 5 people max that this really helps, if it doesn't help anyone else to *find* answers then let's cleanup/combine them, and leave the minor versions out.

Comment: If there's only two `jquery14` questions out there, is it necessary to put in a merge/synonym? Would it not be simpler to just retag them by hand?