# Got a badge today, now my question is missing

Tags: support, questions, badges, specific-question

Logged into day to see the Organizer Badge for [myself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/5/organizer?userid=22514), but the question it is linked to  gets a `Page Not Found`:  [How should versioned jQuery tags be combined on stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57489/how-should-versioned-jquery-tags-be-combined-on-stackoverflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was deleted.

Please see [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60227/please-stop-deleting-retag-requests) for further discussion.

Comment: Thanks.  I wish it has been closed/locked so I could get back my research.

Comment: @Kevin: I posted the content from the question in a separate answer here. I've also voted to undelete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted content:

By Kevin Hakanson (question body):

I was looking at jQuery related tags and noticed the last two major versions account for five separate tags:  [jquery1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery1.3) (32), [jquery1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery1.4) (18), [jquery1.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery1.3.2) (8), [jquery-1.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.3.2) (4) and [jquery-1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.4) (3)

Since the [Official repository of tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms) seems to the `product-x.y` format, I would suggest merging into `jquery-1.3` and `jquery-1.4`, but I wanted to open for discussion.  Also, should this be added to the tag synonyms list?

---

By Nick Craver (answer):

I would recommend **against** merging the minor releases, there are issues in each release, for example a common question is about the `change` event not bubbling in IE (causing `.live('change', func)` breaks).  This issue is specific to 1.4.1 and fixed in 1.4.2 (along with many event questions).

I would recommend mapping:

- [jquery1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery1.3) (32) -> [jquery-1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.3)
- [jquery1.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery1.3.2) (8) -> [jquery-1.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.3.2)
- [jquery1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery1.4) (18), [jquery14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery14) (2) -> [jquery-1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.4)
- [jquery1.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery1.4.1) (1) -> [jquery-1.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.4.1)
- [jquery1.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery1.4.2) (8) -> [jquery-1.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.4.2)

Personally I would leave the minor releases intact, this would result in [jquery-1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.3), [jquery-1.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.3.2), [jquery 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.4), [jquery 1.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.4.1), and [jquery 1.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.4.2).

That being said, leaving only [jquery-1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.3) and [jquery-1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-1.4) wouldn't be all that bad, but the vast majority of questions aren't tagged with a version at all (something I'll start doing in future edits).

*Update:* I moved the jquery1.x.x tags to jquery-1.x.x to at least normalize the formatting for now, there are still a number of jquery1.3 and jquery1.4 out there that need a bulk retag.

---

Comments on answer:

Why would we merge jquery14 with jquery1.4? I thought we wanted to keep major releases separate. – devinb Jul 19 at 18:50

@devinb - jQuery14 is 1.4...1.4 is the latest release, there's no jQuery 14 out there :) – Nick Craver Jul 19 at 18:53

I see your point about minor versions affecting the question, but doesn't this better fit in the question text and not the tag? – Kevin Hakanson Jul 25 at 3:17

@Kevin - I don't think so, my opinion again of course...when I see certain issues I would immediately recognize the issue as a known bug in that version, I would tag questions with those issues with that minor version as well...to indicate it's specific to jQuery-1.4.1 Often the issue doesn't apply to jQuery-1.4 overall, and most people being on the latest (of 1.4 users) wouldn't be affected. That being said, I may be one of 5 people max that this really helps, if it doesn't help anyone else to find answers then let's cleanup/combine them, and leave the minor versions out. – Nick Craver Jul 25 at 12:26