# Unable to retag jsf-2.0 to already existing jsf2

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf-2.0

I just wanted to retag them to `jsf2` because it already exist and there's a lot more of it. It just didn't work. I edited the tag, saved it, but the changes were not reflected nor error'ed in some way. This is regardless of whether I used the quick-tag-edit or the full edit. Newly added tags during edits are however correctly reflected in changes.

It look like that the implicit [tag synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms) retagging has been introduced, but I can't find a note of it and all the "original" synonymous tags are still there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is due to a [tag synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms).  The `[jsf2]` tag was mapped to `[jsf-2.0]`, but a tag merge hasn't taken place yet, so both tags still exist.  New additions of `[jsf2]` will automatically be converted.

**Edit:** I went ahead and did a merge on those two.  We have to do them manually for now.

Keep in mind that if you think a synonym is wrong, we can reverse it (or just remove it) to make it right.  Just make a meta `[retag-request]` post as usual and explain why you think the synonym is wrong.  The synonyms that have been added so far are from the [Official repository of tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms) but nothing is written in stone.

Comment: Thank you. It's a fine choice. I just didn't want to retag the other way round because there's a lot of existing `jsf2` tags :)