# [python-3.x] and [python-3.1] should not be synonyms of [python3]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

[`[python-3.x]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) and [`[python-3.1]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.1) should *not* be automatically renamed to [`[python3]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python3).

- The established tag is `[python-3.x]` with 345 questions, there are currently only four questions tagged `[python3]`
- There can be differences between minor versions of the language that can be important to a question. There are tags like `[python-2.5]`, `[python-2.6]`, ... Also having `[python-3.1]` seems reasonable.
- If there really should be a common tag synonym, it should at least have a dash before the version number (`[python-3]`), to be consistent with all other tags that include version numbers.

I suggest removing these synonyms and leaving the `[python-3.x]` and `[python-3.1]` tags as they are.

Comment: This is a fun game of, Which one of these is a link...

Comment: The ones in the first sentence are links, for the rest I was too lazy...

Comment: @sth, I figured it out.  I hate that the code-links don't have the underline like they should.

Comment: This came directly from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms/50092#50092. Perhaps the visibility wasn't high enough?

Comment: @Justin: Switch to a real browser, like IE7. ;)

Comment: @mmy In IE8 there are no underlines...

Comment: @mmy but in compatibility mode, there are. `>_<`

Comment: Maybe renaming `[python-3.x]` to `[python-3]` would be reasonable to increase consistency with other languages, but `[python3]` without the dash just seems wrong.

Comment: @sth: I agree.  I think `[python-3]` should be the synonym for `[python3]` and `[python-3.x]` with more specific revisions being kept out of it.

Comment: Previous retagging in this context: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2061/change-python3-0-tags-to-python3

Comment: @sth: This question has come up again on [Default tag synonym](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58020/default-tag-synonym/58022#58022).  Would you mind weighing in on that so we can get the Python tags consistent?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that `[python3]` should not be the canonical tag since that isn't consistent with the other tags on SO.  <strike>I've redone the mapping so that `[python-3]` is the main tag, and both `[python3]` and `[python-3.x]` will both be converted.  (My reasoning for doing both is that the `.x` doesn't really add any information.)</strike>

Any other more specific version numbers for Python 3 are left out of the synonyms due to the potential differences that you cited in your second bullet.

I also merged `[python3]` and `[python-3.x]` into [`[python-3]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3) while I was at it.

> #### Update:
>
> After getting some more input on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58020/default-tag-synonym), `[python-3.x]` is now the master tag for Python 3.  Other tags mentioned above are merged and mapped into that one.