# Default tag synonym

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tag-synonyms

I'm not sure how tag synonyms are sorted, but at the moment default tag for `python-3.x` is `python-3`.
I don't have any particular preferences regarding one or the other, but

- it was introduced recently
- no question were tagged `python-3` prior to introduction
- it breaks from the similarly looking `python-2.x`, `python-2.5`, etc. tags

So, my question is whether it would be possible to default to the most popular (used in the most questions) alias. Or whether the voting on the info pages could be an option? (I myself would rather prefer former).

Answer (score 5):

I don't agree with a defaulting process - I think the choice should be made by users, and not through any automation. It should be based not on what has the most tags, but what is the most reasonable. And that isn't something that can be judged by a machine yet. Yes, many times the more used tag will be the one that is the target, but there are many points where a lesser used tag may be more appropriate.

For example, on Meta [vote-totals] has the greatest number, but [split-vote-count] is a more comprehensible term for what the tag refers to (the 1k ability to see upvotes/downvotes, or split vote counts).

As far as how to vote on these, I see it much the same as how retag requests work in the current system - we just post on Meta when we want to bring up an issue.

Comment: tl;dupvote - could you reduce the noise in the last two paragraphs? You made your point in the first two, no need to stretch it.

Comment: @Ladybug Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

How versions are represented in tags is currently rather inconsistent:

- `[c#3.0]`
- `[java-7]`
- `[python-2.x]`
- `[google-maps-v3]`
- `[struts2]`

Generally I think we should aim for more consistency, but only as far as the resulting tag is still idiomatic to the people using it. For example Google Maps seems to always be referred to as "v3", so it can be reasonable to also have it as `-v3` in the tag. People developing for Google Maps should decide if `[google-maps-3]` would look strange to them.

On the other hand I'd guess that the `[c#3.0]` people would also be happy with `[c#-3.0]`. But they probably want to keep the `.0`, even though it serves no real purpose since there are no C# tags for any versions not ending in ".0". But other parts of .Net use version numbers like 3.5 and the ".0" is generally used when talking about C# 3.0, so it makes sense to have the tag `[c#-3.0]`.

Java people on the other hand would probably not like `[java-7.0]` all that much, since it's been a long time since there were any important minor version number in Java (AFAIK).

And for Python, it is important to have tags that refer to the Python 2 or Python 3 "series", as well as tags that refer to the individual versions. Comparing `[python-2]` against tags like `[java-7]` is not all that helpful because Java 7 basically doesn't have any sub-versions while Python 2.4 is substantially different from, say, Python 2.7. It needs to be made as clear as possible to the users that the tag should encompass the whole Python 2.x series (as opposed to Python 3.x).

Probably for `[python-2.x]` and `[python-3.x]` the meaning is more intuitively clear than for `[python-2]` and `[python-3]`. People are used to refer to their Python version as "2.7" and this maps directly to "2.x". Additionally, it worked pretty well with the ".x" tags in the past.

And as a side note: For weblogic there are also tags like `[weblogic-10.x]`, but no tags for any specific version numbers. But someone who knows what weblogic is should judge this.

Comment: While you're saying that we should aim for more consistency, it seems that your whole argument is contradictory to that aim. I think the whole point of tag synonyms is to give user a bit of leeway when tagging question and to help new users with the appropriate tag presentation.

Answer (score 0):

There was a discussion regarding those tags on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57674/python-3-x-and-python-3-1-should-not-be-synonyms-of-python3).  Things are still in flux with tag synonyms, so just let me know what changes you'd like to see to make things consistent.

Comment: well, as I said, for consistency it would be better if the `python-3.x` show up by default. It is not related to `python-3.1` though.

Comment: @SilentGhost: Wouldn't it be better to remove `.x` from the `[python-2.x]` tag?  The `.x` doesn't really add any information.

Comment: @Bill: aside from being visually more uniform, I think it more clearly relays the fact that the question refers to the whole subset of the python versions. I also added `python-2` as a synonym for `python-2.x` tag.

Comment: @Silent: That makes sense.  I'm fine with either convention.  I'm going to wait a little bit for other people to weigh in so we can come to some kind of consensus.  After that I'll change them all to the same style.

Comment: After thinking a while about it I agree with SilentGhost's reasoning and think the tags would be best as `[python-2.x]` and `[python-3.x]`. (See also my answer)

Comment: @Bill: have you changed your mind?

Comment: @SilentGhost: No, I had just missed the updates somehow. Thanks for reminding me.  I went ahead and retagged and remapped synonyms so `[python-3.x]` is now the master tag for Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Marking this as declined.

Some changes in play:

- End users can not propose any synonyms from less popular tags to more popular tags.
- Moderators have override powers in all cases which are very easy to get to

Making this automatic would just needlessly restrict our options as moderators for no real good reason. Moderators need override abilities.

Comment: *override powers in all cases which are very easy to get to*, I wonder where you get this idea from.