# Editing a question to add a tag which is a new tag synonym results in the original old tag being used

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

On Stackoverflow, I've edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312285/java-filters-performance-question) to add the `[servlet-filter]` tag. I know, before the introduction of tag synonyms this tag was called `[servlet-filters]`. During adding the tag, the existing tag `[servlet-filter]` correctly shows up in the autosuggest. After picking it and submitting the edit, the question ends up with the old `[servlet-filters]` tag!

I edited it once again and then once more, but no change. It sticks to `[servlet-filters]`.

Bug?

---

**Update:** it now look like that all original `[servlet-filters]` tags were incorrectly renamed to `[servlet-filter]`. *That* is in turn indeed a bug since it contradicts the [Official Repository](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms/50098#50098).

Comment: Isn't [servlet-filters] the [parent tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=servlet-filters&sort=info&pagesize=50), not [servlet-filter]?

Comment: Then why were all original `[servlet-filters]` tags renamed to `[servlet-filter]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, it looks like the synonym and the merge were done in opposite directions. I've renamed the tag to `[servlet-filters]` now.

Comment: Sorry for abusing comments, but I am a bit confused about what exactly is supposed to happen with tag synonyms. Shouldn't the `[jee5]` and `[jee6]` tags already be merged into `[java-ee-5]` and `[java-ee-6]`? The latter are proposed as tag synonyms and their *info* tab also proves this, but the former tags do still have linked questions? Is it still in kind of beta or is it just another overlook? Isn't this supposed to happen automagically?

Comment: @BalusC: Adding a tag synonym does not automatically perform a merge, at least not at this point. Right now, old questions will only be auto-retagged if they are edited for some reason, if I understand correctly. But I can go merge those right now.

Answer (score 1):

`[servlet-filters]` is the target for the tag synonyms. However, existing questions tagged `[servlet-filter]` have not yet been corrected because tag synonyms do not prompt an automatic retag.

Also, the Official Repository is not necessarily respected by the community. Many tags were created *before* that list was created, and the retag has not been done on all of those tags.