# Please fix the math-related tag synonyms on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

Currently we have:

`[mathematics]` --> `[math]`
`[maths]` --> `[mathematics]`

which is looking pretty ugly.

From the [Tag Synonyms Repository](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms/50089#50089), `[mathematics]` was proposed as the master tag, with synonyms `[math]` and `[maths]`.

Could a mod please fix this?

Comment: Should we just go with `[math]` as the master tag for the group?  It was mapped to `[mathematics]` when the July 16 script was run, but evidently that synonym has been removed and reversed since then.

Comment: @Bill: Sure, that's fine. Personally I'd prefer `[mathematics]` as the master, but if that got reversed, then by all means go with `[math]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made `[math]` the master tag for the group, so we now have:

`[mathematics]` --> `[math]`
`[maths]` --> `[math]`